# Using TensorBoard to visualize error values from CSV file

Tags: tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, tensorboard

I have a CSV file containing loss values after training a Keras neural network model, somthing like this:

```
7.019360989332198431e-01
6.927479231357573930e-01
6.899647492170333241e-01
6.840079456567764726e-01
6.766045588254929743e-01
9.124663196504115281e-02
8.141199145466089526e-02
7.456063829362392925e-02
6.891768645495176260e-02
6.426200993359089397e-02
6.076486252248287923e-02
.
.
.
```

I can use MS Excel to plot it, but actually I want to visualize it using TensorBoard. I know I could have done it easily via TensorBoard class but I missed this chance and I really don't want to go back to train again. Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: You can use matplotlib now